# dictionary keys in JSON output is overwritten: how to index each uniquely? how to make sure the values format not changed?

Tags: python

The code below does mostly what I want: convert the `status` field into a good JSON format but with two problems:

1. (NOT VERY IMPORTANT) The values i.e., `name,from,to,configuration` are all re-arranged in
   alphabetical order. How can I make sure python doesn't re-arrange
   them and output the values in the sequence you see in `status`?
2. (VERY IMPORTANT) In the `status` below, I have two `objects` with same names: `bus,
   train`, so the script is overwriting the first `car` and `train`
   data with the second instance although the values are different
   (most of them). How can I output the JSON keys as: `car_1,
   car_2,...,car_n`? similarly
   `train_1,train_2,...,train_n`,`aeroplane_1,aeroplane_2,...,aeroplane_n`?
   So irrespective of whether I have a repeated key or not, I want to
   index the key at the end.

What I have so far:

```
import re

status = """
Object train {
Name electric_train;
From Seattle;
To Tacoma;
Distance 100;
Configuration train_travel;
}

Object car {
Name honda;
From Richland;
To Seattle;
Distance 160;
Configuration road_travel;
}


Object bus {
Name greyhound;
From pasco;
To richland;
Distance 15;
Configuration road_travel;
}

Object aeroplane {
Name united;
From miami_airport;
To pasco;
Distance 1000;
Configuration air_travel;
}


Object train {
Name gas_train;
From beach;
To miami_airport;
Distance 30;
Configuration train_travel;
}

Object car {
Name toyota;
From apartment;
To beach;
Distance 14;
Configuration road_travel;
}
"""

def Status2dict(status):
    result = {}
    current = {}
    lines = status.splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line: 
            continue
        mo = re.match(r'Object (\w+) {', line)
        if mo:
            curk = mo.group(1)
            current = {curk: {}}
        elif re.match('}', line):
            result.update(current)
            current = {}
        else:
            mo = re.match(r'(\w+)\s+([\w\s]+);', line)
            if not mo:
                raise ValueError('cannot match {!r}'.format(line))
            current[curk][mo.group(1)] = mo.group(2)
    if current:
        result.update(current)
    return result

import pprint    
pprint.pprint(Status2dict(status))
```

My current output:

```
{'aeroplane': {'Configuration': 'air_travel',
               'Distance': '1000',
               'From': 'miami_airport',
               'Name': 'united',
               'To': 'pasco'},
 'bus': {'Configuration': 'road_travel',
         'Distance': '15',
         'From': 'pasco',
         'Name': 'greyhound',
         'To': 'richland'},
 'car': {'Configuration': 'road_travel',
         'Distance': '14',
         'From': 'apartment',
         'Name': 'toyota',
         'To': 'beach'},
 'train': {'Configuration': 'train_travel',
           'Distance': '30',
           'From': 'beach',
           'Name': 'gas_train',
           'To': 'miami_airport'}}
```

In the above output, you can see only one `train, car`.

Comment: Isn't it more standard in json to add an array like cars: [{...}, {....}], vice some sort of car_1, car_2, ..., car_n?

Comment: @sahutchi It is typically [{...},{...}] but this is small part of a larger problem so I got to keep the format the way it is. I am not sure what you mean by the second part of your question.

Comment: I was just implying that if there are multiple cars, you could add those to an array.  In that way, you could have each of those objects which could have a one-to-many relationship you define as an array where you could append each object into the array. If instead of managing those one-to-many relationships as an array, you wanted to treat each instance of car for example as car_x where x was like an auto incremented index then its probably not the most elegant solution but you could write a function that checks status.find('whatever key'), to see if there are duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that seems to satisfy both of your requirements. Basically, keep a running counter of how many times each unique "Object" has been seen.

As for maintaining the ordering of the fields, used an OrderedDict instead of a regular Python dict.

```py
import re
import collections, json

status = """
Object train {
Name electric_train;
From Seattle;
To Tacoma;
Distance 100;
Configuration train_travel;
}

Object car {
Name honda;
From Richland;
To Seattle;
Distance 160;
Configuration road_travel;
}


Object bus {
Name greyhound;
From pasco;
To richland;
Distance 15;
Configuration road_travel;
}

Object aeroplane {
Name united;
From miami_airport;
To pasco;
Distance 1000;
Configuration air_travel;
}


Object train {
Name gas_train;
From beach;
To miami_airport;
Distance 30;
Configuration train_travel;
}

Object car {
Name toyota;
From apartment;
To beach;
Distance 14;
Configuration road_travel;
}
"""

def Status2dict(status):
    # Keeps track of how many times each Object has been seen already
    keys_count = {}

    result = {}
    current = {}
    lines = status.splitlines()

    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line: 
            continue
        mo = re.match(r'Object (\w+) {', line)
        if mo:
            curk = mo.group(1)

            # If Object has not been seen before, start tracking it
            if not curk in keys_count:
                keys_count[curk] = 1

            # Get the current counter value, which we will append
            # to the Object name (e.g. car_<counter>)
            curk_counter = str(keys_count[curk])

            # Increment our running count for this Object
            keys_count[curk] += 1

            # Rewrite the Object name to have the counter now
            curk = curk + '_' + curk_counter

            # Use OD to maintain order of the fields (As requested)
            current = {curk: collections.OrderedDict()}
        elif re.match('}', line):
            result.update(current)
            current = {}
        else:
            mo = re.match(r'(\w+)\s+([\w\s]+);', line)
            if not mo:
                raise ValueError('cannot match {!r}'.format(line))
            current[curk][mo.group(1)] = mo.group(2)
    if current:
        result.update(current)
    return result

print(json.dumps(Status2dict(status), indent=2))
```

### Output:

```
{
  "train_1": {
    "Name": "electric_train",
    "From": "Seattle",
    "To": "Tacoma",
    "Distance": "100",
    "Configuration": "train_travel"
  },
  "train_2": {
    "Name": "gas_train",
    "From": "beach",
    "To": "miami_airport",
    "Distance": "30",
    "Configuration": "train_travel"
  },
  "car_2": {
    "Name": "toyota",
    "From": "apartment",
    "To": "beach",
    "Distance": "14",
    "Configuration": "road_travel"
  },
  "bus_1": {
    "Name": "greyhound",
    "From": "pasco",
    "To": "richland",
    "Distance": "15",
    "Configuration": "road_travel"
  },
  "car_1": {
    "Name": "honda",
    "From": "Richland",
    "To": "Seattle",
    "Distance": "160",
    "Configuration": "road_travel"
  },
  "aeroplane_1": {
    "Name": "united",
    "From": "miami_airport",
    "To": "pasco",
    "Distance": "1000",
    "Configuration": "air_travel"
  }
}
```